# Is there any way to predict aliquot sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic, integer-sequences

Recently I learned about [aliquot sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliquot_sequence). Here's how they work: you start with any number. For an example, I'll use $10$. Then you find all the factors of that number, besides itself. So for $10$, that's $1, 2,$ and $5$. Then you add those numbers up - we get $8$.

Now we repeat this process with this sum. So $8$ has factors $1, 2,$ and $4$, which sum to $7.$ Now we do it again with this sum. $7$'s only factor  besides itself is $1,$ so our sequence goes to $1.$ The sequence ends at $1.$ The full sequence was $10\rightarrow 8 \rightarrow 7 \rightarrow 1.$

I made a program to calculate these sequences, and I have some questions.

> $276$ shoots off to infinity - why does this happen? What makes $276$ special? Is there any way of knowing if it will eventually go back down to $1$ or not?

> Is there any way to predict what will happen to a sequence without simply calculating it? Can we tell if it will loop, go down to $1$, or go up to infinity?

> Does knowing the aliquot sequence of a number tell you anything about multiples of that number? For example, given the aliquot sequence for $10$, can you derive the aliquot sequence for $20$ from it, without calculating it?

These questions have been bugging me for a little bit, and I would really appreciate some answers. Thank you!

Comment: So, the aliquot sequence is defined as $$a_{n+1}=\sigma(a_n)-a_n$$ , right ? I think that this iteration is too  dynamic to have any useful structure.

Comment: Apparently, [this](http://factordb.com/index.php?id=1100000003844791171) number must be factored to continue the sequence for $276$.

Comment: We still have relatively small numbers in the aliquot sequence with start value $276$, so chances of a soon termination are still not too bad.

Comment: Do you know for sure that $276$ shoots off to infinity, or is this an open problem? https://oeis.org/A131884 suggests that this is a "conjecture" i.e. an open problem...

Comment: I don't know for sure. I tested it on my program and it went up to $90$ quintillion - I stopped it because I didn't want to break the computer.

Comment: While playing with numbers, it is very, _very_ easy to stumble upon a simply formulated question that will remain open for centuries. Pierre Fermat can attest to that. In short, not much is known besides what you already know. We don't know whether 276 actually shoots off to infinity. We don't know whether **any number** shoots off to infinity. The only way to know what happens in the end is to traverse all the way to the end and see what is there. Short of that, there is no known way.